# How to walk from north pole to south pole during daylight while minimizing the max speed?

Tags: calculus, optimization, numerical-methods

If we started out at fall equinox, ignoring revolution of the earth and assuming the earth is perfectly spherical, one need to walk from $\varphi = 0$ to $\varphi = \pi$ while maintaining that $0<\theta +\omega_e t<\pi$, where $t$ is time elapsed and $\omega_e=2\pi/\mathrm{d}$. The angular speed $\omega_{t}^2=\dot{\varphi}^2+\dot{\theta}^2\cos^2{\varphi}$ is to be minimized.

Not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Since $\omega_t$ is a function of time (as I understand it), there are several ways you can "minimize" it. Do you wish to minimize the mean value, the $L_2$ norm, $L_p$ norm, supremum ?

Comment: This approach is not quite right or you have to change your question, since near north pole and near south pole "daylight" is totally different.

Comment: @Theleb supremum is what I had in mind

Comment: @AnatoliyR I added in the description that we start out at the fall equinox and ignore the revolution of the earth, so both north pole and south pole would see sunlight

Comment: @arax frankly I missed "fall equinox", not sure, but probably if we "stop the earth" at the moment of fall (or spring) equinox, we can do it